# How can I set maximum length to this regular expression?

Tags: regex

This validation works well for allowing alphanumeric chars, spaces, and a dash, but I have not been able to set the max length to 23.

Regex:
   **(^\w+\s*(-?)(\s*\w+\s*)(\w+)$){0,23}**

The cases I need to pass:

- Winston1-Salem6
- Winston-Salem
- Winston Salem
- 1-two3
- word2 with space

Cases I need to fail:

- -Newberty-Los-
- 12345678901234567890123444

Comment: You're not attempting to set a max length. You've said to match the entire expression from 0 to 23 times, not set a max length of 23 characters.

Comment: Depending upon what you are doing it may work best to just check the length of the string separately, although you should be able to do `(?=^.{0,23}$)`

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be more convenient to check the length separately, but you can use a lookahead to confirm that the entire expression is between 0 and 23 characters.

```
(?=^.{0,23}$)(^\w+\s*(-?)(\s*\w+\s*)(\w+)$)
```

http://rubular.com/r/GVIbG8hDKz

Comment: Did OP specify Perl regex?  This won't be supported everywhere, no?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a look ahead to assert a max length:

```
(?=^.{1,23}$)^\w+\s*(-?)(\s*\w+\s*)(\w+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH6kE9/1)

Or a negative lookahead works too:

```
(?!^.{24,})^\w+\s*(-?)(\s*\w+\s*)(\w+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH6kE9/2)

Variable width [lookaheads](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) are supported in [most](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Part_1) modern regex flavors

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(^-|-$|.{24,})).*
```

> ```
> Winston1-Salem6 - PASS
> Winston-Salem - PASS
> Winston Salem - PASS
> 1-two3 - PASS
> word2 with space - PASS
> -Newberty-Los-  - FAIL 
> 12345678901234567890123444 - FAIL
> ```

---

Demo
https://regex101.com/r/eM3qR9/2

Regex Explanation:

```
^(?!(^-|-$|.{24,})).*

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!(^-|-$|.{24,}))»
   Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(^-|-$|.{24,})»
      Match this alternative «^-»
         Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
         Match the character “-” literally «-»
      Or match this alternative «-$»
         Match the character “-” literally «-»
         Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any «$»
      Or match this alternative «.{24,}»
         Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.{23,}»
            Between 24 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{24,}»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can't total lengths of matches up like you want.

Use

```
/^(\w+([ -]\w+)*)$/
```

and check the length of the group #1 manually after the match.