# How to set maxlength in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created this working regex below, this aims to accept phone numbers only *ex. 09338195838*.

```
^(09)[0-9]{9}
```

However I don't know how to set a maxlength that will accept only 11 digits. **I've been to other similar questions like** [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059292/how-can-i-set-maximum-length-to-this-regular-expression) **but none really helped**, and tried the below code but still it accepts even if it exceeds to 11 digits.

```
((09)[0-9]{9}){11}
```

Here is the detailed structure:

1. must starts with `09`
2. must all numeric
3. must 11 digits

---

Someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^09[0-9]{9}$` 
The $ symbol means "The string has to end, without other characters after this".

Answer (score 3):

You can set word boundry.

`((09)[0-9]{9})\b`

test: https://regexr.com/51c40

if you want to make it more elastic, `not only 11 digit`

you can use `((09)\d{0,9})\b`

`{0,9}` sets the min and max lengths, now it accepts maximum 11 digits starts with 09 and min 2 digits that is 09.

Comment: What you mean "wrapping"? Can you explain more?

Comment: @charles so you dont want exactly 11 length, for example it can be 6 length? or just ```09```?

Comment: Nvm Sir its just the curiosity that push me to ask more, I think more short answer is to @Zoldszemesostoros, but still I upvote this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect solution for the mentioned problem:
^09[0-9]{9}$

I am explaining your thoughts.

- I think you want to wrap the whole regex with max length 11 like this:^(09[0-9]){11}$
  it will not work because when you set this{n}, it repeats the previous term with exactly n times. As you wrap the whole term so it will find the match 11 times that start with 09 following any digit(0-9). Ex:(098093095...). so how much time you set it will find full wrap set between the start to end.

  Please check the link I have set a demo example.https://regex101.com/r/JU8JzV/1